# Realizing or After realizing?

Tags: word-usage

> Realizing that I was interested in the statistical method area, I chose to go to XXX University to study my master in Mathematics and Statistics, in order to make better preparation for my upcoming Ph.D. study.

I am writing my Academic Statement of Purpose to apply for my Ph.D. degree. The above sentence is correct or not correct? I am not sure whether I should use realizing or After realizing. Is there any mistakes in the sentence?

Comment: Either option is fine. General proofreading is off-topic for this site.

Comment: You've established that the action (chose) happened after "realizing", so the "after" would be considered redundant, though not necessarily wrong.

Comment: While your point of concern is valid, adding "*Are* there any mistakes in the sentence?" clearly asks for proofreading which is off-topic.

Comment: "the statistical method area" could be confusing. May I suggest either "statistical methods" or "the area of statistical methods".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference in meaning or grammatical or idiomatic validity between “Realizing that X, I …” and “After realizing that X, I …”.

However, there is a lapse in your proposed sentence. “My master” refers to a person. The usage of the word in English is derived from the Latin word “magister,” meaning “chief” or “teacher.” So you may study a master by studying his works, or you may study with or under a master by studying under his or her direction. I greatly doubt that is what you mean by saying that you went to university X to study under some person named Y or to study the thoughts of person Y. I strongly suspect that you mean that you went to study to gain a master’s degree, which indicates a certain level of knowledge.

In other word,

> study my master

does not begin to describe why you went to that university. You almost certainly went

> to study for my master’s degree